# How can I reverse tether my phone for Internet connectivity via USB cable without rooting?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, android

I'm trying to create an Internet connection for an Android device using a Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 x64) box. Creating a Wi-Fi hotspot proved to be redundant as the device cannot discover the network. Next, I tried going through [the steps described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode/). However, the hardware set up does not support AP interfaces.

I am left with the idea of reverse tethering via a USB cable. However, I do not want to root the phone.

Is there a solution that can solve this issue *without* rooting the device?

The device is running Android 4.2.2. and the workstation’s hardware specifications are:

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter 
USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser!  Not every PC Wifi card can create an actual Access Point, as you discovered.  And.. most Android devices can't connect to Ad-Hoc wireless connections, as you discovered.  I think you should be made aware that you didn't **actually** ask a question.  Oh, I'm sure you can point out some question you implied, but that means we are supposed to guess at what you are asking... and that never works out well.  Could you edit your question to be specific in what you want to know?  And, just as important.. *what* USB adapter are you talking about?

Comment: Ok.  Better Edit.  However, exactly what issue are you talking about, that you need solved?  The issue of your Android device connecting to an Ad-Hoc connection?  Not going to happen.  The issue of you being able to make a true Hotspot with your computer?  Get a wireless card that supports Access Point Mode.  The issue of you using the USB adapter?  You still haven't detailed **what** USB adapter, or what you want to do with it.  Are you calling the cable that you use to connect your phone to your computer an adapter?

Comment: I've realized that an Ad-Hoc network isn't feasible. I basically want to do the opposite of USB tethering, share the workstation's ethernet card with the mobile device using a wired(USB) connection between the two.

Comment: I know you realized that an Ad-Hoc isn't feasible.  That's why I said you discovered it doesn't work.  I've seen YouTube videos detailing Reverse Tethering a mobile to a PC to share the internet from the PC to the Phone... all the videos involved having to root the phone, which you said you don't want to do.  I'm sure your going to say that you already Googled the reverse tethering videos, and while you are aware that they all required a rooted phone, what you are REALLY asking (without asking) is **How to I Reverse Tether my phone without rooting?**

Comment: I never take YouTube videos for granted. Using HTC-Sync Manager on my windows box provided satisfactory results. I was wondering if the same could be done on a linux machine given that I don't have access to that workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this late answer, but it seems you still have not found a solution yet, so I thought I'd chime in:

I was looking for a reverse tethering solution for unrooted devices as well, and could not find one. Eventually, I started to develop my own solution. The result is ReverseTethering NoRoot, an app that works on all Android versions starting from 4.0 on the client side, and all major desktop operating systems on the host side.

The app is available on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?