# How to create and use USB network interfaces on debian platforms?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, debian

This question is basically a follow up on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/644497/how-do-i-reverse-tether-my-phone-for-internet-connectivity-without-rooting) question. When the phone is plugged in and the Internet pass-through option is checked then a new RNDIS device(usb0) should be provided. On ubuntu the /etc/network/interfaces file must be edited in order to create the new device interface.

After altering my interface file, it looks as follows:

```
# default settings
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# used for reverse USB tethering
# auto usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
# auto usb1
iface usb1 inet dhcp
# auto usb2
iface usb2 inet dhcp
```

However, the interfaces are not created as expected. Running ifconfig does not show any new interfaces aside from the default eth0, lo and wlan0. Uncommenting the auto * lines corrupts network initialization. As a result, only the loopback interface is created.

How may I create a dhcp usbx network interface on an ubuntu 12.04 64-bit system?